# Apache2.2 Zend server6 configuration "ites.d/globals-*.conf" was not found" error

Tags: php, zend-server

We are the newbies for `ZEND` server and recently purchased one licence for `ZEND IBM i`. Then we found errors as below at our `Apache2.2` configuration.

```
Include /usr/local/zendsvr6/etc/sites.d/globals-*.conf

File "/usr/local/zendsvr6/etc/sites.d/globals-*.conf" was not found.

Include /usr/local/zendsvr6/etc/sites.d/vhost_*.conf

File "/usr/local/zendsvr6/etc/sites.d/vhost_*.conf" was not found.
```

Eventually we are going to upgrade the version to 8 from this 6, but we'd like to know why this error was happened, and our server is sometimes phenomenally slow at the PHP line, `"DB2_CONNECT"` with the error message, " `executing time out in 30...`", also it errors our ZEND console screen and crush with unknown reasons.

Any kind of your advice would be a big help for us.

Thanks,

beerneko

Comment: After we contact with the support team, then they recommended to use "Reset" from ZEND Menu, so we've done. Once console screen back since then but as soon as execute the app, it's failed again...

Comment: I checked old back ups and it has a same error. ...So it doesn't caused any  issues.

Answer (score 0):

After the days of investigation, this is not related to ZEND Server at all. We found that it's the Hypervisor defect issue which caused by CPU queuing accumulation. This symptoms shows CPU utilization is really low (CPU %), but the hole bunch of the queuing remains. All of these jobs are waiting to get into the processor, even though there should be processor resources available. And this issue only occurs on a couple different models of P8 systems and only when it's used by shared processors.

So, I guess Installing ZEND server is just one of the bunch of misc triggers.